# Using one role at once in Asp.Net Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to solve the following problems:

1. The user can have just one role at time.
2. He can change his current role inside application, without need to logout. For example, he wants to change from "Admin" to "Annalist".

I'm using [this example](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/16/aspnet-core-3-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example-api) as my authorization approach.

In there I can set multiple roles to user, but once he is logged, he has all roles at same time.

Comment: I can see that this functionality would be useful at verifying whether a specific role is capable of performing a specific action, but the easiest approach to this is to open a new incognito tab with a test user that has the one role you want. The admin user can have a ui that will give or take roles to the test user.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I handled this:

- The user has only one "main" role.
- The user has a list of other possible roles.
- When logged in, only main role is active in the claims.
- When switching role, another token is created for the user.